# Touch Swiper Gallery with Individual Thumbs

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, gallery

I am looking to recreate a gallery like this one (http://goldschmiede-gote.de/html/schmuck5.html) with fullscreen pictures and the possibility to have these individual colored thumbs. An added bonus would be to include swipe&touch capabilities for an iPad. 
I tried various jquery plugins (like swiper) but couldn't manage to set a gallery like the above up.
Maybe you guys could point me in the right direction where to look or what plugins to use? In the end it should, if possible, look exactly like the link I posted.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No jquery plugin has such inbuild gallery effect . either u have to create manually or u have to use a gallery template which has been already developed .